# How do you delete/create/rename files after selecting the IIS Physical Path using Powershell?

Tags: iis, powershell

I can query IIS and get the current physical path:
$sitepath = get-website xyz.net | select-object PhysicalPath
but then need to find a file within a subdirectory of this and delete/create/rename. The trouble I am having is that I see error "Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{physicalPath=d' does not exist." for any cmdlet I try to apply to $sitepath.
Many thanks,

Comment: What *is* $sitepath after that line? I suspect it is 1) a hash or other similar object (and not a string) or; 2) a string that quite literally is "@{physicalPath=d:\balhblah..}"

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get a fileinfo or directoryinfo item from the path first.

This will work as long as the PhysicalPath doest contain environment variables (like %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot):

```
$SiteFolder = get-item (get-website xyz.net).physicalpath
$fileInFolder="$($SiteFolder.fullname)\index.html")
$fileInFolder | gm;
$newFileHandle = $fileInFolder.Copy("C:\New\Path\Of\copiedFile")
$fileInFolder.Move("newfilename.htm"); 
$fileInFolder.Move("c:\new\Path\Of\File")
$FileInFolder.Delete()
$fileinFolder | Remove-Item
```

If the PhysicalPath does have system variables in it, Expand the variables into the full path by Expanding it: [Expand Environmental Variables in PowerShell Strings](http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/2012/06/friday-fun-expand-environmental-variables-in-powershell-strings/) and then using the above method to get a reference to the file object.

Comment: great help, thanks. couple of small things (which might be related to PS version, not sure, am using v3 on WS 2008 r2)...

Comment: 2nd line I've changed to:

Comment: $fileInFolder="$($SiteFolder)\index.html"

Comment: I've updated Line2 to reflect the correct property name (FullName, not fullpath; sorry).